# How do I prevent our content editors from posting short URLs

Tags: url-shorteners

Is there a general regex or regularly updated list of short URL domains I can use to validate that links our content editors post on our website aren't using URL-shortener services? We want people to post the original link; since we're also not wanting editors to post visible URLs, there's no need for short URLs. And where there is a legitimate need for a short URL, such as for print or giving over the phone, we want it to have our domain on it for branding (we have a way to produce internal short URLs).

It would be easy to blacklist known .com URL-shortening domains such as tinyurl and digg. But with two-letter top-level domains, it seems like it would likely be a game of whack-a-mole, with new URL-shortening services likely to pop up all the time. Perhaps we could only permit two-letter top-level domains by whitelist, at the risk of slowing the ability of editors to post some legitimate links.

Are there any open solutions that are out there for this? I tried searching on "block url shorteners" (without the quotes) but only got results for URL shortening services or which mention that this site or that block posting such links, without saying how they do it.

A Drupal 7 or CKEditor solution would be ideal, but a generic code solution would work as well.

Answer (score 1):

You'll never be able to fully (or even largely) prevent shortened links from being shared.

You mention tinyurl and digg, but what about Facebook, Twitter, LinkedIn, etc?

Social media aside, there is no shortage of open source (or not) software that allows anyone to set up their own URL shortener, using a domain of their choosing (shorter or not).

This is like asking how to prevent websites from linking to your content.

You can take a whitelist approach or a blacklist approach and either one has huge drawbacks.

If you are really concerned about it, prohibit it in your terms of service for content contributors and ban contributors that don't follow the policy.